# Install sqlserv in docker nanoserver

Tags: apache, docker, odbc, sqlsrv, server-core

We have been using Docker and the public repository ***nanoserver/wamp*** in Dockerhub in implemeting our project. We've been able to use the system as we use PHP and an external MySQL server for our database.

Now, our database is shifting to MSSQL and in order to access MSSQL we need to have sqlsrv .dll files in the C:\php\ext folder

But one pre-requisite of the sqlsrv is the MSODBC driver and I cannot find a way to download an .msi file inside nanoserver because of its restrictions.

Is there a way to just copy and paste the ODBC files into the nanoserver so we can use sqlsrv into our php project? Or are there any way to connect to an MSSQL database?

I have tried this, but it's still not working:

```
COPY msodbcsql13.dll C:/Windows/System32/
COPY msodbcsql11.dll C:/Windows/System32/

COPY msodbcdiag13.dll C:/Windows/System32/
COPY msodbcdiag11.dll C:/Windows/System32/

COPY msodbcsqlr13.rll C:/Windows/System32/1033/
COPY msodbcsqlr11.rll C:/Windows/System32/1033/
```

Basis for the files is from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files?view=sql-server-2017

I haven't tried the public repository ***microsoft/windowsservercore*** as it offers IIS-PHP, and we need an **Apache-PHP** configuration and I do not know how to set it up there. By any chance, if it only work with this repo, can you point me on how to install Apache-PHP in ***microsoft/windowsservercore***?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there is really no way to install sqlsrv into nanoserver since it requires installing the dependencies with an .msi filetype.

I'll just share how to setup apache-php setup into ***microsoft/windowsservercore***

> Here's my *dockerfile*:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

COPY setup c:/apache

ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x86.exe /apache/vc_redist.x86.exe
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x64.exe /apache/vc_redist.x64.exe
RUN C:\apache\vc_redist.x86.exe /quiet /install
RUN C:\apache\vc_redist.x64.exe /quiet /install

COPY Apache24 c:/Apache24

COPY php c:/php

RUN powershell.exe -command \
    cmd.exe /c c:/apache/service.bat; \
    sc.exe config apache2.4 obj=LocalSystem; \
    remove-item c:/apache -Recurse
```

- Apache repository came from https://www.apachelounge.com/download/
- PHP repository from https://windows.php.net/download/

> Here's the content of my service.bat:

```
cd\
cd Apache24\bin
httpd.exe -k install
```

- My basis for the overall installation is from: https://docs.moodle.org/35/en/Manual_install_on_Windows_7_with_Apache_and_MySQL

> After installing the Apache-PHP setup, I was able to install msodbcsql.msi and insert sqlsrv.dll and pdo_sqlsrv.dll for PHP, and it showed up in the phpinfo();